# UnhandledThrownError! Cannot destructure property 'categories'of '(0 , react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useSelector)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Auth.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {},
  },
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.user = payload.user;
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = {};
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
    },
  },
});

export const { setUser, logout } = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

index.js  (store)

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authReducer from "./auth.js";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
  },
});
```

transaction form.js

`const { categories } = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);`

** when I logged in there was a error but on reloading the page the error is gone. How to fix the error**

Answer (score 0):

If you are not logged in, you don't get a user, and then you cannot extract categories from it. Several solutions, one is

```js
const { categories } = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user ?? {categories: []});
```

Depending on what you do with the user and category data, you might be better off doing something like this:

```js
const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);
if(!user){
  return;
}
const categories = user.categories
...
```

Comment: after this i getting error in this line 
`const category = user.categories.find((category) => category._id === id);`

Unhandled Thrown Error!
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'categories')

Comment: Yes, because you are doing the same thing as before. Updated my answer, maybe it helps.

Comment: error is resolved with this syntax but when i logged in i didn't  get my data
i need to reload it again

Comment: Any initialization that needs a user and was skipped when there was none has to be repeated once a user is available (or user changes).

Comment: `const { categories } = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user ?? { categories: [] });
  function categoryName(id) {
    const category = categories.find((category) => category._id === id);
    return category ? category.label : "NA";
  }`



Now I am getting NA when logging first time after reloading i am getting correct data
@MoritzRingler